# How to bind result in UNION with IN clause in Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, union

I am trying to write query for UNION prepare statement with IN clause. I am binding array with call_user_func_array() but no result is showing. I think there is no problem with binding array.

here is my code

PHP code :

```
    if(isset($_GET['subject'])) //subject is array of subjects
    {

    $search1 = $_GET['subject'];

    echo $subject_count = count($search1);

    echo $subject_csph = implode(',', array_fill(0, $subject_count, '?'));  // comma-separated placeholders

    $total_count = $subject_count * 14;
    $total_params = array_merge($search1, $search1, $search1, $search1, $search1,
                            $search1, $search1);

    $param_string = str_repeat('s', $subject_count * 14);  // write s chars before i chars


    $construct .="(subject in ($subject_csph) or subject in ($subject_csph)
          or subject in ($subject_csph) or subject in ($subject_csph) or subject in ($subject_csph)
          or subject in (subject_csph) or subject in (subject_csph))";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("(SELECT id,year,name,city FROM student1 WHERE $construct) union all (SELECT id,year,name,city FROM student2 WHERE $construct)"); 

    if($stmt){

    array_unshift($total_params, $param_string);  // prepend the type values string

    $ref = [];  // add references
    foreach ($total_params as $i => $v) {
        $ref[$i] = &$total_params[$i];  // pass by reference as required
    }
     call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $ref);    

      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt1->bind_result($id,$year,$name,$city,$id,$year,$name,$city);

      $count = 0;
      while($stmt1->fetch()){
      echo $id;
      $count++;
        }
        echo $foundnum=$count; 
       }
    }
```

there is no error in error log. what is wrong i am doing here?

Comment: You are aware that the shown SQL is redundant? You repeat the condition 7 times (including two typos, which otherwise make the query fail) and the query twice ...

Comment: there is IN clause so i have to pass 7x the number of binds to balance between placeholders and bound variables

Comment: i was doing one thing wrong here i have to pass 14x times because of 2 union  select. now i getting $count.

Comment: query running right but how to bind result in UNION? please tell me.

Comment: Since both queries are the same you don't need a UNION.

Comment: i edited my question there are two different tables in union student1 and student2

Comment: Now your WHERE condition lacks the differentiation between the tables. This usually results in a database error.

Comment: i am not getting any error. can you suggest my question to someone?

Comment: You are not using PDO, you are using mysqli. I edited the title and tags to clarify this.

Comment: i solved my problem i was binding result twice that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed

```
$stmt1->bind_result($id,$year,$name,$city,$id,$year,$name,$city);
```

to

```
$stmt1->bind_result($id,$year,$name,$city);
```

and it works for me.